# KOMA-Script's addmargin environment in combination with caption command

Tags: captions, koma-script

I want to use KOMA-Script's addmargin environment (oneside document only) to sometimes write stuff using the full width of my document, which is divided into 2/3rd text area and 1/3rd margin.

This works... until I realized the caption command doesn't take the whole width as I want, see (my current code (only the necessary parts I think)):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside=false,paper=a4,DIV=15,BCOR=0mm,twocolumn=false,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,mpinclude=false]{scrreprt}% KOMAScript
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
    %% Margin
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-\marginparwidth}%
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{\marginparwidth}%
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{.333\textwidth}%
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{-\marginparwidth}%
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{\marginparwidth}%
}\recalctypearea%


\newlength{\overhang}%
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}%
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}%
\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
    \begin{addmargin}[0em]{-\overhang}%
}{%
    \end{addmargin}%
}%


\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    %% Works as intended
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{fullwidth}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{fullwidth}
    %% Problem with caption
    \newpage
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This caption is centered as it should be. \lipsum[1]}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{fullwidth}\centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{The image is centered, but the caption is NOT ugh... \lipsum[1]}
        \end{fullwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is: [image][image][image]
Can someone explain to me how to solve this problem? I just want the caption to use the full width as the image obviously. If possible with the addmargin environment, since I already use it very often in my document. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addmargin` is a `trivlist`. AFAIK, it does change `\linewidth` but neither `\textwidth` nor `\hsize`. But the `\caption` width seems to depend on these. So, use for example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside=false,paper=a4,DIV=15,BCOR=0mm,twocolumn=false,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,mpinclude=false]{scrreprt}% KOMAScript
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
    %% Margin
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-\marginparwidth}%
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{\marginparwidth}%
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{.333\textwidth}%
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{-\marginparwidth}%
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{\marginparwidth}%
}\recalctypearea%


\newlength{\overhang}%
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}%
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}%
\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{addmargin}[0em]{-\overhang}%
    \textwidth\linewidth\hsize\linewidth% added
}{%
    \end{addmargin}%
}%


\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    %% Works as intended
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{fullwidth}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{fullwidth}
    %% Problem with caption
    \newpage
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This caption is centered as it should be. \lipsum[1]}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{fullwidth}\centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{The image is centered, but the caption is NOT ugh... \lipsum[1]}
        \end{fullwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: using the whole width of the addmargin for the caption]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solves my question. <3 
Last question: It also works if I only set `\hsize` to `\linewidth` so is there any advantage or disadvantage to set `\textwidth` too? (Edit: I think `\textwidth` should already be the full length anyway or?)

Comment: AFAIK `\textwidth` is the width of the text area only, not the width of the `addmargin` environment, because `addmargin` is not a `minipage` but a `trivlist`. You can test the values adding `\the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\hsize` after `\begin{addmargin}`… I've set `\textwidth` in the example, because I often see code using `\textwidth` for images with `\includegraphics`, etc.

Comment: I see. Than setting both to `\linewidth` is the better option here, I can't at least see any negative consequences. Thanks a lot. :)